# Need to kill multiple PID's got from tasklist in windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Please help me on killing multiple PID's (java.exe) when we get it from below command:

```
echooff  
for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%G in ('tasklist /FI "imagename eq java.exe" /FI "modules eq service.dll" /NH /FO CSV') DO set str=%%G  
set str=%str:~1,-1%    
echo %str%    
if not %str%==0 taskkill /pid %str% /f    

Output of above script is:    

"java.exe","1234","Services","0",95.400 K"    
"java.exe","2345","Services","0",95.400 K"  
"java.exe","3456","Services","0",95.400 K"  
"java.exe","4567","Services","0",95.400 K"  
"java.exe","6789","Services","0",95.400 K"
```

Now I need to kill these all pid but this command is just killing the PID from last line.
Please suggest how can I kill these all PID's

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, I have got the solution for this issue.

Just execute below command and that will fix this:

taskkill /F /FI "imagename eq java.exe" /FI "modules eq service.dll" /FI "PID gt 0"